# "Can't locate object method "new" [...]" in Perl using the AI::Pathfinding::AStar CPAN module

Tags: perl, oop, new-operator

This is the first "serious" thing I'm doing in Perl, so please pardon me if the question is somewhat silly.

I wanted to play around with the A* pathfinding algorithm. I found the [AI::Pathfinding::AStar](https://metacpan.org/pod/AI::Pathfinding::AStar) CPAN Module and am basically trying to get the given example to work.

First of all I separated the example into two files, because I couldn't figure out how to make the `use My::Map::Package;` work with everything in a single file. I came up with the following two files:

MyAstar.pm:

```
package MyAstar;
use warnings;
use strict;
use base "AI::Pathfinding::AStar";

my %NODES = get_all_nodes();
sub get_all_nodes {...}
sub getSurrounding {...}
```

main.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

package main;
use lib '/home/foo/astar/';
use warnings;
use strict;
use MyAstar;

my $map = MyAstar->new or die "No map for you!";
my $path = $map->findPath(1, 5);
print join(', ', @$path), "\n";
```

When I execute main.pl I get the following error:

> Can't locate object method "new" via package "MyAstar" at main.pl line 9.

I'm not sure what the problem is here. I would have expected, there to be a subroutine by the name `new` in the `AI::Pathfinding::AStar` package, but couldn't find it. Is the CPAN Module broken or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Note that there are some sample uses cases in the package's [test file](https://metacpan.org/source/ACDALTON/AI-Pathfinding-AStar-0.10/t/01_AI-Pathfinding-AStar.t). Seems like you have to define a `new` method in your `MyStar` package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to call a function (`MyAstar->new`, which conventionally is used as a constructor), but you don't define it. There is no default constructor in Perl (like in e.g., Java).

Add something like this to your MyAstar.pm:

```
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = bless{}, $class;
    # initialize $self here as needed, maybe using any passed arguments in @_
    return $self;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot! I expected that the CPAN module (so the Parent class of MyAstar) was supposed to provide the `new` subroutine.